# Given multiple implementations how does Spring decide which implementation to inject?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I see in our codebase that we're directly injecting dependencies in the constructor instead of using `@Autowired`. My question is - how does Spring determine which dependency to inject when there are multiple implementations? Here's some sample code:

```
  public class UserDetailsService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    public UserDetailsService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
     this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
```

Let's say there are 2 different custom `RestTemplate` configuration annotated classes returning 2 different variations of it. Does Spring favor one over the other or does it randomly pick one implementation and goes with it? I understand that we can use `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier` to choose our preference but what is Spring's default preference or if there is any at all?

Comment: [1.9.4. Fine-tuning Annotation-based Autowiring with Qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) Documentation is always the way to go

Comment: By default spring uses the class name with the first letter lowercase for the bean name. So if you have two different implementations it can easily pick which one as they will have different class names. If you have two beans registered with the same bean name and attempt to inject it you will get an error of multiple bean definitions found and will have to specify an @Qualifier